# Typescript - Sort generic array

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm trying to implement a function in `typescript` where the user can pass an `array` of objects and a property of one of the objects and return the list order by the property the user have chosen.

```
function OrderByArray(values: any[], orderType: any) { 
    //TODO: implement code
    return values;
}
```

Is any way to do it? I know how to sort an array but I don't know how to allow to send the typeof object and order by it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you need to allow types as arguments? It's supposed to represent the sorted property?

Comment: The reason is because I'm working on a function where I have to receive an array and I don't know the object type and I have to return the values sorted by the object.property sent by the user. @Martin

Comment: Why you don't use just `property: string`?

Comment: So, how could I sort the user array[] by a string? I mean think about the user can send a person[], car[]... etc and ask to order by `year`, `name`, `carbrand`.. I don't know if you can get me. @Martin

Comment: You want to sort the array by multiple properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```
function OrderByArray(values: any[], orderType: any) { 
    return values.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[orderType] < b[orderType]) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (a[orderType] > b[orderType]) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0
    });
}
```

I'm not sure what's the value of `item[orderType]`, so you might need to change the `if`s.

---

#### Edit

Using it:

```
let animals = [{ name: "cat" }, { name: "dog" }, { name: "lion" }];
let cars = [{ manufacturor: "ford" }, { manufacturor: "mazda" }, { manufacturor: "fiat" }];

console.log(OrderByArray(animals, "name").map(item => item.name)); // ["cat", "dog", "lion"]
console.log(OrderByArray(cars, "manufacturor").map(item => item.manufacturor)); // ["fiat", "ford", "mazda"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20OrderByArray(values%3A%20any%5B%5D%2C%20orderType%3A%20any)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20values.sort((a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BorderType%5D%20%3C%20b%5BorderType%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(a%5BorderType%5D%20%3E%20b%5BorderType%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%200%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20animals%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20name%3A%20%22cat%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22dog%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22lion%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0Alet%20cars%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20manufacturor%3A%20%22ford%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20manufacturor%3A%20%22mazda%22%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20manufacturor%3A%20%22fiat%22%20%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(OrderByArray(animals%2C%20%22name%22).map(item%20%3D%3E%20item.name))%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22cat%22%2C%20%22dog%22%2C%20%22lion%22%5D%0Aconsole.log(OrderByArray(cars%2C%20%22manufacturor%22).map(item%20%3D%3E%20item.manufacturor))%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22fiat%22%2C%20%22ford%22%2C%20%22mazda%22%5D))

---

#### 2nd Edit

In [typescript 2.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#user-content-21-november-2016) you'll be able to do:

```
function OrderByArray<T, K extends keyof T>(values: T[], orderType: K) {
    ...
}
```

[More about keyof](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11929).

Comment: it could work, let me integrate it in my code, but not sure yet. thanks @nitzan-tomer

Comment: in the first edit you did could be possible something like -> `OrderByArray(values, orderType).map(item => item.orderType)` ? @nitzan-tomer

Comment: If `orderType` is a variable then you need to do: `OrderByArray(values, orderType).map(item => item[orderType])`

Comment: great! thanks! I'm pretty new using typescript. @nitzan-tomer

Comment: with regard to your 2nd Edit, it should be

`function OrderByArray<T, K extends keyof T>(values: T[], orderType: K) {
    ...
}`

Comment: @chris.currin Fixed. It was a while ago, before the feature was actually out, maybe back then it was just `keyof T`, not sure or remember.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to return the results of values.sort(...) as [mentioned in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> Array.sort actually changes, or mutates the array it sorts